# Alamofire and iOS app extensions

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire with an iOS app share extension and I wanted to know if there was a flag that would get rid of this error.

(null): Linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

There is a way in AFNetworking to do (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2321). Is there something similar for Alamofire?

**Solution:** If Alamofire is imported as a framework, one can simply choose the Framework target, and under the General tab, check the Allow app extension API only box.

Comment: It's better to answer your own question than to edit an answer into the question itself. You even get points for it, I think.

Comment: do you mean "Require only App-Extension-Safe API" under Build Settings/Build Options?

Comment: your answer is not clear, please answer your own question